# Can @Epic have dynamic values in Allure report. I need to pass my API name like @Epic(ApiName), Where ApiName is a String

Tags: allure

Can @Epic have dynamic values in Allure report.

I need to pass my API name like @Epic(ApiName).

Private String ApiName = getApiName();
@Epic(ApiName)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Allure.getLifecycle() api solved this problem.
ex:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "customer", dataProviderClass = GetUserData.class)
    public void CommonMethod(UserData data) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        AllureLifecycle lifecycle = Allure.getLifecycle();
        final Label label =  new Label().setName("epic").setValue(data.getApi());
        lifecycle.updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.getLabels().add(label));
        
        
        //testing code
}
```